# Yield and default case || do not output default case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have a simple yield use case and for some unknown reason the default case is never shown:

In my super_admin layout I have:

```
<%= yield :body_id || 'super_admin_main' %>
```

**My controller**

```
class Superadmin::GolfsController < ApplicationController
  layout "super_admin"

  def show 

  end
end
```

**My show view**

With or without

```
<% content_for(:body_id) do %>sadmin_golfs<% end %>
```

**With**: sadmin_golfs is shown.

**without**: **empty string is shown instead of super_admin_main**

Can anyone reproduce the same behavior ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
<%= (yield :body_id) || 'super_admin_main' %>
```

Or

```
<%= yield(:body_id) || 'super_admin_main' %>
```

Without them it is assuming `yield (:body_id || 'super_admin_main')`

EDIT: Rails 3 uses `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` instead of string/nil (Rails 2), so the output is not nil even if there is no `content_for` provided. So try:

```
<%= yield(:body_id).empty? ? 'super_admin_main' : yield(:body_id)%>
```

Comment: Actualy it stills shows an empty string when no content_for is supplied.

Comment: You do not suppy `content_for` at all or it is just blank like `<% content_for(:body_id) do %>  <% end %>` ?

Comment: How about when trying to render a partial? Looking for the ability to overwrite a sidebar in specific views: `<%= yield(:sidebar).empty? ? 'special_sidebar' : yield(:sidebar) %>`

Comment: missed `.presence` --> `yield(:body_id).presence`

Answer (score 27):

Try `<%= yield(:title).presence || 'My Default Title' %>`

`Object#presence` is equivalent to `object.present? ? object : nil` (AS 3 rc docs), and essentially allows the traditional syntax with the titles.

Comment: this is the better answer for rails 3

Answer (score 3):

Why no test if there are a content_for or not define in view compilation.

In the content_for code we can see :

```
def content_for(name, content = nil, &block)
  ivar = "@content_for_#{name}"
  content = capture(&block) if block_given?
  instance_variable_set(ivar, "#{instance_variable_get(ivar)}#{content}".html_safe)
  nil
end
```

So in your case, the `@content_for_body_id` is define if a content_for is in your view.

You can made :

```
<%=  instance_variable_defined?('@content_for_body_id') ? yield(:body_id) : 'super_admin_main' %>
```

If you prefere you can generate an helper after

```
def yield_or(part, result)
  instance_variable_defined?("@content_for_#{part}") ? instance_variable_get("@content_for_#{part}") : result
end
```

and call it in your view by

```
<%= yield_or(:body_id, 'super_admin_main') %>
```

It's works only with Rails 2.3.x

**In Rails 3 :**

there are this method [content_for?](http://api.rails.info/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#M002277)

Answer (score 1):

**In rails 3**

raises undefined method `present'

Comment: The most elegant solution I've found so far (without gems). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I have a solution for Rails 2.3.

I've extended [shingara's yield_or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907245/yield-and-default-case-do-not-output-default-case/2911522#2911522) helper method above so it can now accept a block:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def yield_or(name, content = nil, &block)
    ivar = "@content_for_#{name}"

    if instance_variable_defined?(ivar)
      content = instance_variable_get(ivar)
    else
      content = block_given? ? capture(&block) : content
    end

    block_given? ? concat(content) : content
  end
end
```

and this can be used in your templates:

```
<% yield_or :something do %>
    <p>something else</p>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= yield_or :something, 'something else' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class= <%= (yield :content_with_bunners).present? ? yield(:content_with_bunners) : "col-md-10"%>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `content_for?(:body_id)`, the code will be like.

```
<%= content_for?(:body_id) ? yield(:body_id) : 'super_admin_main' %>
```