# Rails 3: yield/content_for with some default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

Is there any way to detect if `#content_for` was actually applied to a `yield` scope in Rails?

A classic example being something like:

```
<title><%= yield :page_title %></title>
```

If a template doesn't set that with

```
<% content_for :page_title, "Something here" %>
```

Is there a way to have the layout put something else there instead?

I tried defining it with `#content_for` in the layout itself, but this just causes the text to be doubled-up.  I also tried:

```
<%= (yield :page_title) or default_page_title %>
```

Where `#default_page_title` is a view helper.

This just left the block completely empty.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use `content_for?` to check if there is content with a specific name:

```
<% if content_for?(:page_title) %>
  <%= yield(:page_title) %>
<% else %>
  <%= default_page_title %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= content_for?(:page_title) ? yield(:page_title) : default_page_title %>
```

Then in your views you can specify the content like

```
<% content_for :page_title do %>
    Awesome page
<% end %>
```

Comment: content_for?(:title) || 'This is a default title' is shorter and works ;) and too:  content_for :page_title, 'Awesome Page'

Comment: `<%= yield(:title).presence || 'Default Title' %>` is better way for solution.

Answer (score 17):

As of Rails 3, `yield()` returns empty string if there was no content for the requested key, so you can do something like this:

```
<title><%= yield(:page_title).presence || 'Default Page Title' %></title>
```

In your application helper, if you define:

```
def page_title(title = nil)
  title ? content_for(:page_title) { title } : content_for(:page_title).presence
end
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
<title><%= page_title or 'Default Page Title' %></title>
```

And in your views you can customize with:

```
<% page_title 'My Page Title' %>
```

Answer (score 6):

Better answer for rails 3 here:

[Yield and default case || do not output default case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907245/yield-and-default-case-do-not-output-default-case)

`<%= yield(:title).presence || 'My Default Title' %>`

Answer (score 5):

I have just released a new gem, [dry_views](https://github.com/pboling/dry_views), which provides enhanced content_for methods.

The benefit over the accepted answer is it allows you to remove all logic (if/else) from your views.

See the readme for extensive examples:

`- no_content_for :key`

- Use a dash (-) not equals (=)
- Will prevent a later content_for from rendering.  This allows template overrides of layouts.

`= content_for_with_default :key`

- Use an equal (=) not a dash (-)
- You provide it with the default HAML via a block *or* a set of params that are the same as you would pass to a standard "render" call (i.e. :partial => 'foo', :locals => {:bar => 'bar'}).`

`= content_for :key`

- Use an equal (=) not a dash (-)
- You provide it with a block, i.e. {render :partial => 'foo'}, and it will override content_for_with_default.  It has the same precedence as no_content_for, so whichever is rendered first wins, so if a layout has either no_content_for or content_for (with or without default) the template can now override it.